# "libnfc Installation" /usr/lib/libnfc.5.dylib: Operation not permitted

Tags: installation, nfc, kiosk

OS X: El Captain

I am trying to install libnfc-1.7.1 as RFID Reader Kiosk for (ACR122U).
It worked on raspberry pi from this [url,](http://chocolatechips.me/how-to-raspberry-pi-rfid-reader-kiosk-acr122u/) but the libnfc's installation was unsuccessful on my mac.

#### had Installed MacPorts-2.3.4-10.11-ElCapitan

#### Then executed these commands on terminal:

```
                         // just comments
sudo port -v selfupdate // stack overflow 

sudo port upgrade outdated // suggested by terminal 

sudo port install libusb-legacy //source libnfc community website
```

The rest of the steps were from this [link](http://chocolatechips.me/how-to-raspberry-pi-rfid-reader-kiosk-acr122u/):

```
wget https://bintray.com/artifact/download/nfc-tools/sources/libnfc-1.7.1.tar.bz2
tar -xvzf libnfc-x.x.x.tar.gz
cd libnfc-x.x.x
./configure --prefix=/usr -sysconfdir=/etc
make
brew update && brew upgrade
sudo make install
```

#### a warning showed up while executing "make":

```
 arygon.c:94:22: warning: unused variable 'arygon_error_incomplete_command'
          [-Wunused-const-variable]
    static const uint8_t arygon_error_incomplete_command[] = "FF0C0000\x0d\x0a";
```

I even tried:
`make clean && make`

### later on "sudo make install" errored:

```
~/Downloads/libnfc-1.7.1$ sudo make install
Making install in libnfc
Making install in chips
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in buses
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in drivers
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in .
test -z "/usr/lib" || .././install-sh -c -d "/usr/lib"
 /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libnfc.la '/usr/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libnfc.5.dylib /usr/lib/libnfc.5.dylib
install: /usr/lib/libnfc.5.dylib: Operation not permitted
make[3]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 71
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

#### The error message is simialr to this [issue](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/openexr-user/2006-08/msg00001.html)

> The user admin privileges were verified.

#### An issue was opened on libnfc's [github](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/issues/340), but no one is answering since February.

## Please help me get the libnfc installation sorted out as RFID Reader Kiosk if possible.

Comment: I attempted this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391722/os-x-permission-denied-for-usr-local-lib. It did not work

Comment: I am still working around this: https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/issues/42 . I guess it might help find an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into [similar problem](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/issues/330). I had a hunch that libusb might be involved.

[libsub](http://www.libusb.org)
normal installtion steps:

- `./configure`
- `sudo make`
- `sudo make install`

After that installing libnfc-1.7.1:

- `./configure`
- `sudo make`
- `sudo make install`

libnfc is running from my  mac El Captain. 
This is straight fresh from Terminal:

```
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
error   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    Unable to claim USB interface (Resource busy)
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: acr122_usb:001:006-072f-2200-00-00
```

At the moment libnfc is telling something from the terminal, but not recognizing nfc tags.

I will be researching now

this is working:

[but not efficient](https://www.mail-archive.com/pcsclite-muscle%40lists.alioth.debian.org/msg00273.html)

...up to date possible solutions could be found here:
[#330 github](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/issues/330)

I have attempted most of them except for the ext dummy kernal.

Comment: hope this help someone else